# My C code compiles but won't execute, and I don't know why

Tags: c, cs50

My code is below:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int points[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        print("Player 1 wins! \n");
    }
    else if (score2 > score1)
    {
        print("Player 2 wins! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        print("Tie! \n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(word); i < len; i++)
    {
        if isupper(word[i])
        {
            score += points[word[i] - "A"];
        }
        else
        {
            score += points[word[i] - "a"];
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

I expected it to execute, and I still don't know why it didn't. It keeps saying "Permission denied" when I try to run the file, although the "make" function works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the message after `make` or after executing your program? If the latter is the case, `chmod +x your_program` (on unix like os, similar on others ) might fix your problem (if the e**x**ecution bit was not set). Other than that, it is mysterious why you're denied permission. Does `make` only compile or does it do other things too?

Comment: after that, your next problem will be `- "A"` and `- "a"`. You need to change the double quotes to single quotes, `- 'A'` and `- 'a'`. The double quotes denote a string literal, the single quotes a character, those are two very different things. I strongly suspect your compiler should be warning you about that.

Comment: If it's saying "Permission denied", there's a good chance that you're trying to run the `.c` file, instead of running the executable. Show us the command line you used to compile, and the command line that you're using to run the program.

Comment: Are you sure, your program compiles? What does your compiler have to say about `word[i] - "A"`? Subtracting a pointer from an integer won't fly. If you get warnings or errors from your compiler, you must read, understand and fix them before running your program. And if you struggle to solve a message from the compiler, copy&paste the complete and exact message as formatted text directly into the question.

Comment: What is `print` function? Should this be `printf`?

Comment: If I compile your code (after removing cs50.h, get_string and string type), I get a warning about using function `print` without declaring first. Is that something from cs50 headers? And I get 2 errors `error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int’ and ‘char *’)` regarding `word[i] - "A"`. Therefore I have some doubts you really compiled your code successfully and hence cannot run it.

Comment: "Permission denied" errors when trying to launch a program is almost always caused by the executable still running in the background since a previous attempt. So when you tell the compiler to rebuild your executable, the OS refuses it, because the previous executable is still running. Which OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: @Lundin I think you meant errors when trying to build the program, not "launch" it. (That is a problem on Windows, but not a problem on OS/filesystem combinations that allow open files to persist after file deletion.)

Comment: @IanAbbott Most programmers use an IDE these days, so building and launching tends to be the same hotkey.

Comment: @Lundin My IDE is a Bash shell. :-) (Actually, multiple Bash shells.)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have `Execution Permission` for the file.

If you do `ls -la` you see somthing like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 hexatech hexatech 4096 Feb 14 09:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 hexatech hexatech 4096 Feb 13 13:51 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hexatech hexatech  511 Feb 13 14:45 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 hexatech hexatech  347 Feb 14 09:00 main.c
```

The left part `drwxr-xr-x` tell information about the file.

The `d` at start is for `Directory`, and `rwx` is for `read`, `write` & `execution`.

You have 3 time's `rwx`, in order is for `User`, `group`, `other`.

You can change the file Permission with `chmod` command.

For more info use `chmod --help` or/and `man chmod`.

when you use `make`, that call a `Makefile` and he set that permission for you.

Comment: The compiler normally sets correct permissions to the output file.